# AutoHotkey choking on same-line curly brace for compound if statements

Tags: compiler-errors, autohotkey, curly-braces

I have a problem where AutoHotkey tells me there is a missing `{` in front of  an 'else' where I think my Code is perfectly fine. (It worked up until I changed the window-related if's from Pidgin to qutIM)

```
^!p::
   IfWinExist ahk_class QWidget, ,qutIM {  ;if there is a qutIM-window other than the buddy-list...
      IfWinNotActive ahk_class QWidget, , qutIM {  ;ans it is not active...
         WinActivate
      } else {  ;the closing bracket in front of the else here puts AHK off...
         WinMinimize
      } 
   } else {  ;do some stuff with the buddy-list
      ; [...]
   } 
return
```

I fear I'm overlooking something stupid, but I cannot seem to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the One True Brace style is usable only with pure If statements, not with compounds like IfWinExist.

[From the documentation for if-expressions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm):

> The One True Brace (OTB) style may optionally be used with
>   if-statements that are expressions (but not traditional
>   if-statements).

Ie. you have to use WinExist() form, not IfWinExist.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the Solution for my problem (but I still wonder why it worked before then o.O)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Apparently, you answered yourself your question, which is a good thing... :-)

Answer (score -1):

[As PhiLho stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829306/3357935), the The One True Brace (OTB) style can't be used with compound if-statements.

While there isn't a direct function for `WinNotActive()`, you can use `!` as a modifier for the same effect.

```
^!p::
   if WinExist("ahk_class QWidget", , "qutIM") {
      if !WinActive("ahk_class QWidget", , "qutIM") {
         WinActivate
      } else {
         WinMinimize
      } 
   } else {
      ; [...]
   } 
return
```

Answer (score -2):

Since I don't have the app you're testing it on I'm not really sure what you're trying to get it to do but this might be another way to go:

```
^!p::
IfWinExist, ahk_class Notepad ; if there is a qutIM-window other than the buddy-list
    {
    WinActivate
    Exists=True
    }
else ;the closing bracket in front of the else here puts AHK off...
    {
    WinMinimize
    Exists=False
    }
If Exists=True 
    MsgBox, do some stuff with the buddy-list ; dummy code
Else
    {
    Msgbox, Exiting App ; dummy code
    ExitApp
    }
```

Comment: it was about opening/hiding the chat-window of an multi-window IM-Client...
As PhiLho pointet out i was just using the wrong notation for my if's, but thank you anyway ;)