# Is there a functional equivalent to 'if WinNotExist()'?

Tags: autohotkey

One limitation of AutoHotkey's syntax is the lack of `not` modifiers for pure if statements.

```
IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad       ; valid
IfWinNotExist, Untitled Notepad      ; valid
If WinExist("Untitled - Notepad")    ; valid
If WinNotExist("Untitled - Notepad") ; invalid
```

While this normally isn't an issue, this can become troublesome when adhering to [Egyptian Brackets/One True Brace (OTB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1828197/3357935) style.

> The One True Brace (OTB) style may optionally be used with
>   if-statements that are expressions (**but not traditional
>   if-statements**).
>   <sub>- [AHK documentation on if-statements](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm)</sub>

The combination of these two issues has left me unable to put in a simple error check to validate whether or not a window exists.

```
IfWinNotExist, Untitled - Notepad {  
    Return   ; invalid
}

If WinNotExist("Untitled - Notepad") {
    Return   ; invalid
}
```

The only solutions I've found is to either break OTB style and put my bracket on a newline, or use a unnecessarily redundant if-else statement.

**How can I check if a window doesn't exist in AutoHotkey with a function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a simple solution: **Use `!` as a not modifier.**

```
If !WinExist("Untitled - Notepad") {
    Return
}
```

Or as [Robert Wigley suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925652/is-there-a-functional-equivalent-to-if-winnotexist/45925965?noredirect=1#comment78816828_45925965):

```
If not WinExist("Untitled - Notepad") {
    Return
}
```

Comment: Or just use: if not WinExist()